# connecting to google drive for creating a google sheet

Tags: bash, curl

Hi I am currently trying to write a bash script to upload/edit/create an google sheet but am currently having issues with how I would curl the API.

I have looked into the gdrive tool however it seems google has revovoked its certificate and looking for an example of just a pure curl while using the authentication program seems un-fruitful.

I would appreciate if anyone has any resources or even just a good example of a bash script

Comment: Did you try google? there are a plenty of resources for and examples of the  script  that you want to create.

Comment: could you provide a url because googling this I couldn't find it, most directed me to setting stuff up in the google developer console or the google data apis which are not the same as the google sheet apis